# Can't find a link button in a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a link button in a repeater with a couple of databound fields. I'm trying to get to where I can set the buttons onClientClick after the databinding however everytime I try to access the link button I keep getting Null returned.

I've looked through every single question involving repeaters and controls here and haven't been able to figure it out.

The .aspx

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="DailyRepeater" OnItemCommand="DailyRepeater_ItemCommand" runat="server">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="coltitle">
                                Time
                            </td>
                            <td class="coltitle">
                                Activity
                            </td>
                            <td class="coltitle">
                                Hours
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr class="evenrow">
                            <td>
                                <%# Eval("StartTime","{0:HH:mm}") %>-<%# Eval("EndTime","{0:HH:mm}") %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%# Eval("Description") %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%# Eval("Hours","{0:0.0}") %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                   <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CausesValidation="false" ID="editbutton" Text="Edit">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
```

The .aspx.cs

```
    protected void DailyRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton myButton = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("editbutton");
        myButton.OnClientClick = (popupWindow.GetTargetPopupCode("URL");
    }
```

From what I've read, I should have been able to get to the button using the RepeaterItemEventargs. However I can't seem to find it here. The other thing I thought of was that the binding wasn't happening by the time this happened (which made no sense to be as this is a databound event) but for some reason e is coming back e.Item has a dataItem of null and an itemIndex of -1...

I'm just really confused and lost any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you haven't guarded against the item type. Typically, it fires the header, all the items, and then the footer. You need to do this:

```
 if(e.Item.ItemType == ItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ItemType.AlternatingItem)
 {
      LinkButton myButton = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("editbutton");
      myButton.OnClientClick = (popupWindow.GetTargetPopupCode("URL");
 }
```

Comment: Ugh, hours of searching for a more complex answer and it comes out I wasn't checking for the right type... sigh. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not setting the property on the `sender` object, like this:

```
sender.OnClientClick = //whatever//
```

Comment: sender is of type "Object", which does not have an OnClientClick property.